# Multiple integer arguments with getopt?

Tags: c, getopt

What is the best way to handle multiple integer arguments while using getopt? I have to be able to enter something like this on the command line: `calc -a 100 50` and it will add up 100 and 50.

```
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "adms")) != -1)
    {

       value = atoi(argv[optind + 1]);
      printf("value : %d\n", value);

        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a': aFlag = 1; num1 = atoi(argv[optind]);
                  sum = num1 + value;
                  printf("%d + %d =  %d\n" , num1, value, sum);
                  break;
        case 'd': dFlag = 1;
                  break;
        case 'm':  break;
        case 's':  break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unknown option %c\n", argv[0], optopt);
return 1;
        }
    }

     if (aFlag == 1)
        {
                  num1 = atoi(argv[optind]);
                  sum = num1 + value;
                  printf("%d + %d =  %d\n" , num1, value, sum);
        }
     if (dFlag == 1)
        {
                  num2 = atoi(argv[optind]);
                  sub = num2 / value;
                  printf("%d / %d =  %d\n" , num2, value, sum);
        }
```

Comment: Can you change your API to `-a 100 -a 50`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Nope, I know about that solution but I'm not allowed to do that. i have everything else done but I have no idea how to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: change your API to `-a "100 50"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I wish I could do that. It would be so much easier.

Comment: Another technique, essentially the same as BLUEPIXY's suggestion, is to separate the arguments by commas: `-a 100,50`.  There is even a function, [`getsubopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsubopt.html) to support comma-separated `name=value` pairs as an argument to a program, though it is not widely used.  The basic `getopt()` function doesn't support multiple arguments for a single option — you either have to write your own or work out how to diddle the implementation on your system (look at the source code) or redefine the interface to avoid the trouble.

Comment: Do you just need to treat the numeric arguments as 'file name' arguments.  You get one operator option (`-a`, `-s`, `-m`, `-d`) rejecting the command invocation if someone uses two or more of them, and then check that there are two arguments unused.  Or, for `-a` and `-m`, you could allow more than two other arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the interface you're after is probably:

```
./program -a 100 50
```

which accepts a single option `-a` (alternatives `-m`, `-s` and `-d`), and then processes the other arguments as a list of numbers, rather than as values attached to the option.  This works fine unless you planned to be able to use:

```
./program -a 100 50 -m 20 30
```

to do addition and multiplication.

What do you want to do if someone can't make their mind up and tries:

```
./program -am 100 50
```

Should it be an error, or should `-a` or `-m` win?  You can argue for any of those with some degree of coherency.  I'd go with an error, though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int op_add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
static int op_sub(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
static int op_mul(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
static int op_div(int a, int b) { return a / b; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (*fun)(int, int) = 0;
    char op;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "adms")) != -1)
    {
        if (fun != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: you can't use two operations\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a': fun = op_add; op = '+'; break;
        case 'd': fun = op_div; op = '/'; break;
        case 'm': fun = op_mul; op = '*'; break;
        case 's': fun = op_sub; op = '-'; break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unknown option %c\n", argv[0], optopt);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (fun == 0 || optind + 2 != argc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-adms] num1 num2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int res = fun(atoi(argv[optind]), atoi(argv[optind+1]));
    printf("%s %c %s = %d\n", argv[optind], op, argv[optind+1], res);
    return 0;
}
```

The error checking on the values in the 'numeric' arguments is reprehensibly sloppy (meaning, non-existent).  There's no division by zero check, either.  But that at least produces plausible answers.  It would probably be better to have an array of structures saving the function pointer and the operation character, but that sort of refinement is for you to deal with.

If you need a negative number, use `--` to mark the end of the options:

```
$ ./program -m -- -39 -75
-39 * -75 = 2925
$
```

Just in case you're not sure about it, `int (*fun)(int, int)` is a pointer to a function that takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int` result.  It allows the code to select which function to execute at runtime.

Comment: Thank you this helped alot. I have one more question. What if he wanted to run something like 'calc -a 100 20 -s 50', in which this does 100 + 20 and 50 - 20. What adjustments show we make?

Comment: At that point, the standard functions don't handle the scheme.  You either have to write a option parser that can handle such requests (I have one, but it's a pretty big sledgehammer for a moderately small nut), or you fall back on an ad hoc parsing technique (which is hard to make as resilient as the funcitions), or you redesign the interface, or you study the internals of the option parsing code you're using and work out how to tweak it into working as you want.

Comment: Can you see my edit. 20 should be held in the variable value and then we use to do the calculations.

Comment: I think it's fair to say I wouldn't be coding it like that.  There's a depressingly straight-forward way to handle the requirement, but the specs for `getopt()` give no reason to expect it to work, even though it does appear to work. I'm debating whether I dare provide the information; I think not — it is absolutely unsupported.  But, you could find code for GNU `getopt()` and then validate that it would work against that.  Grrr!  I land myself in a mess, sometimes.

Comment: I actually got that part working and I finished my assignment. Thanks for all your help! It wasn't that difficult, if you want to see it I could show you what I got.

Comment: I'm happy you're happy and on your way. No need to show your solution unless you think it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

With `getopt()`, an option can take at most one argument.  If you want your program to handle its command line with `getopt()`, and it must accept arguments such as you describe

> ```
> calc -a 100 50
> ```

, and you must not repeat options, then the only viable solution is to make one or both of the integers *non-option arguments* instead of arguments to the `-a` option.  I'd suggest making both (or all) non-option arguments.  Thus, you might have something like this:

```
int result = getopt(argc, argv, "asmd");

switch (result) {
    case 'a':
        // careful: getopt() will be confused by negative numbers
        if (getopt(argc, argv, "asmd") != -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s -a|-s|-m|-d <operands>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
        do_add(argv + optind);
        break;

    case 's':
        // ...
}
```

After `getopt()` returns -1, `optind` is the index in `argv` one past that of the last option (+/- option argument) processed.

Comment: Does that work if someone runs `./program -mad`?  And how does it work with `./program -m -a 100 50 -d`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the example handling for option 'a' throws an error if there are additional options on the command line.  If the handling for the other options does the same then both of your proposed commands will be rejected.  Obviously, I am supposing here that the program is only supposed to accept one option, as my usage message shows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, The case of `./program -a 50 100 -m` is a bit trickier, though: with GNU `getopt()`, that will be rejected by default, too, because the GNU implementation looks past non-option arguments to find additional options.  POSIX `getopt()` (or the GNU version running in POSIX mode) does not do that, so you would need additional validation in the code that consumes the non-option arguments to handle that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This excerpt from the man page for `getopt()` clearly shows that each of the answers (and the original question) are not showing an understanding of `getopt`:

*optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters.

    If such  a  character is followed by a colon, 
        [then] the option requires an argument, 
        so getopt() places a pointer 
            to the following text  in  the  same argv-element,

            or  the  text  of the following argv-element, 
            in optarg.*

your code should also allow for the following:

*If  getopt() does not recognize an option character, 
        it prints an error message to stderr, 
        stores the character in  optopt,

        and  returns  '?'.*

and finally this (which will allow for the `-` to be in any position on the command line:

*By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that
       eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.*